# PERN stack deploying to Railway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, postgresql-14

Hi I've just finished a PERN project that I want to deploying using Railway, should be very easy according the people on the internet.

But I'm just so lost even to begin, I tried connecting to my Github, and I run into a an error already.

[image]

Then I wanted to try deploy my local postgres db first, so I set up the postgres db on railway, got the config pages and change my local postgres config to match railway...and then I'm lost

[image]

[image]

I tried searching on Youtuber and google, but it seems most people are either migrating from heroku, using django, or just not really showing how to deploy from beginning to end.

So I'm here looking for help to see if anyone could guide me to the right place (article or video) that actually shows or teaches how to deploy PERN stack to railway from step 1, which is after finishing the project locally.

A bit more info about the stack I'm using...

1. react 18
2. express.js
3. postgresql 14
4. node 16

BTW, I don't know if this is way I run into the first issue with Nixpacks, but I have my client (react) folder and server (express + postgres db) folder inside a project folder.

Thank you all so much, I appreciate all the help.